# C++ light switch with two buttons: if bar, do x & set foo=1; if thing and foo=1, do y & set foo=0

Tags: c++

How would I write a C++ program that basically has a "switch" that when pressed checks boolean `bar` and if `bar` is true turns off the "lights" and sets boolean `foo` as true so that when a different "switch" is pressed if `foo` is true it turns the "lights" back on and unsets `foo` (or just sets it to false). How would that work? Thanks!

Comment: Post your code first.

Comment: IS this a GUI, I mean will the user click a button?

Comment: No, but an event does trigger it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe could be illustrated like below. There is however nothing in this that assigns `true` or `false` to `bar` since you left that part out of the question:

```cpp
if(a_switch.is_pressed()) {  // "a "switch" that when pressed
    if(bar == true) {        //  checks boolean bar and if bar is true
        lights.turn_off();   //  turns off the "lights" 
        foo = true;          //  and sets boolean foo as true"
    }
}

if(a_different_switch.is_pressed()) { // "when a different "switch" is pressed
    if(foo == true) {                 //  if foo is true
        lights.turn_on();             //  it turns the "lights" back on
        foo = false;                  //  and unsets foo (or just sets it to false)"
    }
}
```

---

You mentioned events in the comments and in an event driven system it may look something like this:

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

class Button { // a better name than switch for something that is pressed
public:
    template<class Func>
    void RegisterCallback_Press(Func&& cb) {
        callbacks_press.emplace_back(std::forward<Func>(cb));
    }

    void Press() {
        for(auto& cb : callbacks_press) cb(*this);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(Button&)>> callbacks_press;
};

class Light {
public:
    Light(std::string label) : label(std::move(label)) {}

    template<class Func>
    void RegisterCallback_On(Func&& cb) {
        callbacks_on.emplace_back(std::forward<Func>(cb));
    }

    template<class Func>
    void RegisterCallback_Off(Func&& cb) {
        callbacks_off.emplace_back(std::forward<Func>(cb));
    }

    void TurnOn() {
        if(!state_on) {
            state_on = true;
            std::cout << "Light::On(" << label << ")\n";
            for(auto& cb : callbacks_on) cb(*this); 
        }
    }

    void TurnOff() {
        if(state_on) {
            state_on = false;
            std::cout << "Light::Off(" << label << ")\n";
            for(auto& cb : callbacks_off) cb(*this); 
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::function<void(Light&)>> callbacks_on;
    std::vector<std::function<void(Light&)>> callbacks_off;
    bool state_on = false;
    std::string label;
};
```

Then setting up the events according to your description:

```cpp
int main() {
    bool bar = true;
    bool foo = false;

    Button a_button, a_different_button;
    std::vector<Light> lights{
        {"Kitchen"},
        {"Livingroom"}
    };

    a_button.RegisterCallback_Press([&](Button&){
        if(bar) {
            for(auto& light : lights) light.TurnOn();
            foo = true;
        }
    });

    a_different_button.RegisterCallback_Press([&](Button&){
        if(foo) {
            for(auto& light : lights) light.TurnOff();
            foo = false;
        }
    });

    a_different_button.Press(); // does nothing
    a_button.Press();           // turns lights on
    a_button.Press();           // does nothing
    a_different_button.Press(); // turns lights off
}
```

This would output:

```
Light::On(Kitchen)
Light::On(Livingroom)
Light::Off(Kitchen)
Light::Off(Livingroom)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/57jsofvE8)

Comment: Thank You! I didn't need the setting of bar because that exists elsewhere.